# Change the content of a string within an array of strings

Tags: iphone, objective-c

This is my code:

```
NSString *newString = @"new value"; 


[breakdownCollection objectAtIndex:i] = newString;
```

breakdownCollection is an NSArray of multiple strings. I need to access a given string contained in the array via index number, and change the string's content to that of the new string. Note that I cannot simply replace the string with the new one, I am only trying to replace its contents.

When I try to do this, however, I get an "lvalue required as left operand of assignment" error.

Any help with this issue would be very much appreciated!

Comment: Why can't you replace the string with a new one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error you get is because you wrote the assignement instruction incorrectly. That is, you **cannot** assign `newString` to `[breakdownCollection objectAtIndex:i]`.
Also, you won't be able to do it this way. Instead, in order to modify string object content, use `NSMutableString`, which provides methods to do so (`NSString` are immutable objects).
So, for example you should try :

```
[[breakdownCollection objectAtIndex:i] setString:newString];
```

assuming you put `NSMutableString` into `breakdownCollection`.

PS : in order to change the object at the index `i`, you have to use `NSMutableArray` instead of `NSArray`, and then call :

```
[breakdownCollection replaceObjectAtIndex:i withObject:newString];
```

Good luck !

[NSMutableString class reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableString_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

[NSMutableArray class reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableArray_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Answer (score 1):

Use an `NSMutableArray` instead and then you can use the method `-replaceObjectAtIndex: withObject:`